# Different values for array first index and dereferenced pointer to first index

Tags: c

I have the following struct and a function to initialize it (typedef taken from .h and `snake_init()` from .c):

```
typedef struct snake_t {
    size_t len;
    int *x, *y;
    int *head_x, *head_y;
} Snake;

Snake *snake_init(int x, int y) {
    Snake *s = malloc(sizeof(*s) + 2 * sizeof(int));
    s->len = 1;

    s->x = (int *) (s + 1);
    s->y = (int *) (s + 2);
    *(s->x) = x;
    *(s->y) = y;

    s->head_x = s->x;
    s->head_y = s->y;
    return s;
}
```

And my main.c (only `int main()` shown):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Snake *s = snake_init(12, 1234);
    // 12 1234
    printf("*x: %d  *y: %d\n", *(s->x), *(s->y));
    // 12 1234
    printf("*head_x: %d  *head_y: %d\n", *(s->head_x), *(s->head_y));
    // 1 1
    printf("x == head_x: %d  y == head_y: %d", s->x == s->head_x, s->y == s->head_y);
    return 0;
}
```

Even though they point to the same address, `s->y` and `s->head_y` have different values when dereferenced. `s->x` and `s->head_x` don't have this problem. What's wrong with the above code? Does it have something to do with the initialization of `s->x` and `s->y` in `snake_init()`?

Comment: It might have something to do with s->y pointing to unallocated memory

Comment: I believe I've allocated memory for both s->x and s->y, given the 2 * sizeof(int). Is this not the way to do it?

Comment: `s + 2` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: yes, but that memory is not where you're pointing `s->y`  `(s + 2)` is (s offset by 2 x sizeof struct Snake) not (s offset by 2 x sizeof int)

Comment: What you're doing is dangerous. At no points does C guarantee that the allocated memory is correctly aligned 
for the members x and y. If it isn't you get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+-------+---+---+
| snake | x | y |
+-------+---+---+
s      s+1
```

In order to access the ints after "snake" do something like this

```
int* x = (int *)(s+1);
int* y = (int *)(s+1) + 1;

s->x = x;
s->y = y;
```